# Joomla Upgrade 1.5.15 to 1.5.23

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to upgrade joomla 1.5.15 to 1.5.23

I have downloaded the Joomla_1.5.15_to_1.5.23-Stable-Patch_Package from the joomlacode.org.

While trying to install this package from my administrator, the error will be displayed "Error! Could not find an XML setup file in the package.".

Or

Shall I extract this zip file and upload the files to server directly through FTP?

Please advise me..

Any help appreciated.

Comment: joomla update package cannot be installed through admin installer. you have to upload file through FTP

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a 3-step process personally to ensure the best possible outcome.

First - backup your site (I LOVE Akeeba Backups 1-touch backup solution); download the backed up site and install on a local host or development server.

Second, do your upgrade there (extract the files from the .zip and put them in the localhost/dev server installation).

Make sure that the upgrade didn't break anything, that everything still works appropriately and as expected and create a backup of the localhost/dev server site.

At that point you know the upgrade won't break anything.

Third, upload the unzipped files from version 1.5.23 via FTP into your root joomla directory (complete the upgrade as listed [HERE](http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_1.5_from_an_existing_1.5x_version).

Doing these steps will ensure the best possible outcome and will show absolutely ZERO disruptions on your live site in the event something you're currently using doesn't like the jump from .15 to .23 - which is a large jump and a lot of things are different (including which version of mootools is included!)  So take caution and TEST FIRST!

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to do this::
Assuming you have access to all the files of website.
1.Now download directly 1.5.23 or 1.5.26 version(last update patch of this series.)
2.Extract the files and open them,you will notice them you need to only replace 4-5 files in that patch.
3.Copy each file and replace them with the current files in the existing websites.

Hope this helps.