# Updating Joomla 1.5.15 to 1.5.26 but no extension manager

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

Right now I am in the process of updating my Joomla 1.5.15 site, so I am trying to follow this.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_I_upgrade_from_Joomla!_1.5_to_3.x%3F

However, I found out that I had to first upgrade to site to 1.5.26 before doing 2.5x or 3.0x. So I am trying to backup the site using Akeeba Backup.I download it. But the problem is that when I go on my site to install the extension, I cannot find the extension manager.

[image]

I am not sure what exactly to do. I have tried doing research but most resources assume that the extension manager is currently on your sight and I cannot find anyone in the community who has the same problem.

[Joomla Upgrade 1.5.15 to 1.5.23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819088/joomla-upgrade-1-5-15-to-1-5-23)

Answer (score 1):

You're not logged in with the right permissions.

To access the Extensions Manager you need to be logged in as a "Super Administrator".

When you do login with the right permissions you will see more menu options and your screen will look something like this:

[image: Joomla 1.5 Adminstrator Screen after login by Super User]

You will need to find the right account name and details before you can use the extension manager.